# Extracting Peaks From Signal Spectogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I was working on a audio file to plot a spectogram from the audio.wav file. I went through the code on the scipy documentation.

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 500*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.25*time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*3e3*time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_po wer), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time/5)
x = carrier + noise
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Now the plot looks somewhat like this. [plot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qytFO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qytFO.png)

Now this plot is frequency vs time. I want to extract the y-value at the peak points (or max value). Is there any way I can do it?

Remember this plot is based on functions we manually create.In case of audio file everything will be randomised.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency of the maximum signal can be found via

```
f[np.argmax(Sxx, axis=0)]
```

You may plot this as

```
m = np.argmax(Sxx, axis=0)
plt.plot(t,f[m], color="crimson")
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.peterjbentley.com/heartchallenge/spectrograms1.jpg

Help me out a bit more on this
If you look at the plot above, I need to identify the max peak.
I had a look at the f[m] values, can you explain what those values are exactly and how do I obtain the single highest point in the frequence vs time plot?

Comment: `f[m]` are the frequencies of the maximum signal. E.g. at time `t[i]` the signal is maximal at a frequency of `f[m][i]`. I don't know what the plot you link to shows, so I don't understand the problem with it.